# How to set GTK+ theme for X-Window application?

Tags: linux, x-windows, gtk

I'm connecting to my Ubuntu server (its actually a VirtualBox virtual machine on the same physical box) using putty and xming.

Is there a way to set my GTK+ appearance/theme so that my GTK+ apps don't look so bland?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`~/.gtkrc-2.0` on the server:

```
gtk-theme-name = "Clearlooks"
```

See `/usr/share/themes`.

---

Other useful settings:

```
gtk-icon-theme-name = "Tango"

gtk-icon-sizes="gtk-menu=16,16:\
                gtk-button=16,16:\
                gtk-small-toolbar=16,16:\
                gtk-large-toolbar=16,16:\
                gtk-dnd=16,16:\
                gtk-dialog=16,16"

# ICONS, TEXT, BOTH, BOTH_HORIZ
gtk-toolbar-style = GTK_TOOLBAR_BOTH_HORIZ

gtk-font-name = "DejaVu Sans Serif 9"
```